# Android: add multiple ListView with TextView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to add multiple listviews (each listview has a textview for the title) in my linearlayout.

All listviews are inserted in programmatically way because I don't know how many listview need in the activity.
My problem is that if I insert TextView+ListView in my linearLayout (without ScroolView) only some of theme are showed (to fill linearLayout).

I tried to insert a ScrollView around the LinearLayout but all listViews collapse (only one item is showed). I know that is not a good practice to insert lisviews in scrollviews.
Do you have any ideas about solving my problem?

I want this situation:

TextView

ListView

TextView

ListView

....
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Place each in a linear layout and set their height weights to equivalent values so that they take up the same amount of space in your parent view.

Comment: @zgc7009 So you say that i have to create a LinearLayout for each list?

Comment: @zgc7009 I want that all listView's items are visible for each group, not that groups occupy the same space..

Comment: Don't have to but you can. When I get a minute I'll see if I can't write up some code